# When I hit alt+tab, VS code do auto save, and formats code, how to stop it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, formatting, prettier, autosave

When I hit alt+tab, VS code do auto save, and formats code, how to stop it?

Whenever I write some code and go to another tab by pressing alt+tab then VS Code auto saves the code and formats it. But I don't want this functionality. How to stop it?

[image: these are all the settings and note: I am not using "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange"]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541, [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this could happen if you have the following combo of settings:

```json
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
```

Just tinker with those settings (and the related ones) until you get what you want.

There might also be bugs with the feature, such as was found and fixed in issue ticket [#206475](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/206475), which looks like it might be the same issue you're having: when `files.autoSave` is set to `afterDelay` and `editor.formatOnSave` is set to `true`,

Comment: I have the same problem despite having `"files.autoSave": "afterDelay".`

Comment: I created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/206475

Comment: Hi, I am not using "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange" but still the problem persists, I have also added image of settings.json

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/206475) in VS Code which caused AutoSave to trigger `editor.formatOnSave` even when `files.autoSave` is set to `afterDelay`.

The March 2024 release includes the fix for this bag (release date: 4 April 2024).